# How to add columns (years) dynamically into crystal report?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I am in the process of creating crystal report document with c#.net 4.0, and can't add columns into report dynamically.

Field view is as following:
[image: Report field view]

Thanks in advance, 
Best,

Comment: This sounds like a "crystal reports" question more than a C# one... but: what kind of data source are you using here? where is it getting the data from? An object model? a DataSet/DataTable? the database directly?

Comment: the data source used in this topic is the DATASET